# Protractor does not perceive a quick change

Tags: promise, jasmine, protractor

This is my protractor test:

```
it("should check email validity", function(){
      var resetButton = element(by.id('reset-button'));
      element(by.model('Contact.email')).sendKeys('nick');
      element.all(by.css('.form-control-error')).each(function (elem, index) {
        if (index===1) {
           expect(elem.isPresent()).toBe(true);
           element(by.model('Contact.email')).sendKeys('@gmail.com').then(
             function(){
              expect(elem.isPresent()).toBe(false);
             }
           )
        }
      });  
    });
```

Behind that code there is a form with some input texts. The **second** one includes the email.`form-control-error`is an error message which appears whenever the email format is not correct. The first time `expect(elem.isPresent()).toBe(true);`passes the test, the second time it does not, even if the error message disappears from the UI. It seems that Protractor does not perceive the fast change; however, it should because it is inside a **promise**. Do you have any explanation for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make things more reliable by adding a wait for the [element to become not present ("stale")](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions.prototype.stalenessOf) after sending the keys:

```
element(by.model('Contact.email')).sendKeys('@gmail.com');

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.stalenessOf(elem), 5000);
expect(elem.isPresent()).toBe(false);
```

Comment: I am getting the following message:  Failed: Wait timed out after 5007ms

Comment: I found the problem! I used ng-show instead of ng-if